# How to use SMTP or Office 365 account in ASP.Net IIdentityMessageService?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms, asp.net-identity

I used to use web.config to configure my SMTP account in order to be able to use send email function but ASP.Net Identity is asking for Email Services. How can I use SMTP or Office 365 email in the following area:

### Register.aspx.cs

```
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text );

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");

                signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

### IdentityConfig.cs

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {


        // Credentials:
        var credentialUserName = "test@test.com";
        var sentFrom = "test@test.com";
        var pwd = "testpassword";

        // Configure the client:
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client =
            new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");

        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        // Create the credentials:
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential(credentialUserName, pwd);

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        // Create the message:
        var mail =
            new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(sentFrom, message.Destination);

        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;

        // Send:
        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);


        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        //return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

### Web.Config

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network defaultCredentials="true" enableSsl="true" host="smtp.office365.com" port="587" password="password" userName="username" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my problem.

Comment: You seem to know already how to use SMTP to send email, and the comment in the sample code clearly shows you where to plug in your code to send the email. I think you have enough to accomplish your goal, but you just haven't *tried*. What's your question?

Comment: Thanks Mason, I actually tried it but it doesn't send any email out. I'm using my email to send Authentication code.

Comment: Where did you try it? I don't see your attempt at it. The only code I see in your question is the default code that comes with Identity. Please edit your code into your question.

Comment: Please see above under Register.aspx.cs, after registration the user should receive an email.

Comment: You still have not made an attempt to actually send the email. Are you familiar with `SmtpClient` class? You should be using that inside the `EmailService.SendAsync` method.

Comment: I'm kind of lost with the identity framework. I thought I'm familiar enough but apparently I'm not...

Comment: Is your Office365 SMTP service set to 2-Factor or MFA authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `EmailService.SendTaskAsync` there's a comment that tells you where to plugin your email code. That's where you'd put your SMTP code, or your call to Office 365 API's, or a web service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). Here's an example of using SMTP.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        //create a client, it should pick up the settings from web.config
        var client = new SmtpClient();

        //now construct a MailMessage object from the message
        var email = new MailMessage("donotreply@mysite.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);

        //send the email asynchronously
        await client.SendMailAsync(email);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Obviously, you might want to move your actual email code to another class so that you can reuse it for other email related tasks.

Comment: This is awesome. Is there any issue with "await", because it's not allowed. I tried it without await and worked perfectly.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell I've noticed you're using Web Forms. You have to take special care to take advantage of async/await in Web Forms. I'm not familiar with it, I usually avoid async in Web Forms. So you can safely remove it and just do `client.Send(email)` if you want to avoid it in this case. By the way, are you set on usign Web Forms? MVC is a better architecture (and I say that as someone that has used Web Forms for a long time ).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Web Forms. I actually wanted to try MVC but I have never used it and I'm afraid by trying it out I might delay my whole process. I fully agree with you that MVC is much much better and has a better architecture...

Comment: I'm using Web Forms mostly because of Code behind things, so on every page I have a code behind to control the movement of the application but I think MVC is not quite like that... Correct?

Comment: @KevinMaxwell Well of course if you've got a deadline, stick with what you know. But in your spare time, check out MVC. Among the benefits, async/await is easy. Those allow you to lighten your server resource usage and in some cases to parallelize your code and get results to the client faster. And correct. Instead of a code behind, MVC uses controllers, and their purpose is somewhat similar to the code behind but they shouldn't do any UI related work. The controller should serve as in between code for your UI layer and your data layer.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell I've found the best way to learn MVC was to watch video tutorials on YouTube or Channel 9. Microsoft has put some great videos together. When you see it in action, it'll click in your head and you'll have a lightbulb epiphany style moment when you'll just "get it".

Comment: I really like your teaching style. Are you a teacher/professor? As you just said MVC uses controller but I assume the controller functions and codes are totally different from what I normally use in the code behind on Web Forms, correct?

Comment: I was going to ask you about learning resources. I actually learned the Identity stuff on Channel 9 from MVA.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell Instead of a `Page_Load`, you'd have an action method. That action method is responsible for calling out to your data layer to retrieve data, or for passing data to the data layer for saving/updating stuff. The action method also picks what View to return to the client, and passes the data that the view needs to render itself. I'm not a teacher, just a Business Systems Analyst doing IT work for my company that is self taught on ASP.NET. Since I'm self taught, I'm able to pick up on common misunderstandings and convey information in a way that I think is easy to learn.

Comment: You are simply amazing, I wish I was able to give you 10+ stars or check-marks to say thank you. This thread actually helped me beyond what I asked for. I will start to watch MVC tutorials tonight ;)